# Using C# to run remote PowerShell code looses information through serialization?

Tags: c#, powershell, serialization

For various reason I need to query the mailbox auto-reply configuration for a user using a remote PowerShell command from C# code instead of using the EWS API.

I'm pretty much using [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) as a template on how to do this and I'm running into an issue that I can't wrap my head around. Specifically it looks like there is some information being lost through the serialization/deserialization process for remote PowerShell commands. So I'm not able to cast it to another type and use it in the C# code. Would anyone have an idea how to either find a workaround or avoid this?

Down below you can see the code that runs the PowerShell code and returns the objects and tries to do stuff with it. The problem is that the `BaseObject` type is `PSCustomObject` and as such the cast/check doesn't work. I am not sure how I'd access the attributes that are exposed by the custom object either. With the debugging tools in VS I'm able to see that it actually kind of has all the data. If I run the code directly in PowerShell I can see that the data type for `$configuration` would be `Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Management.MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration`. So I guess it actually looses some of the information for that object during serialization?

An alternative problem I haven't checked yet (as I'd really like to avoid it) would be that the system I'm running this code on doesn't have the Exchange assemblies installed. That's also why I'm using the clunky `BaseObject.GetType().ToString()` method in order to check the type as I'm not able to reference the type and use `is`. But I'd actually kind of expect to get a data structure that is self sufficient from the PowerShell object. Am I wrong about how this would work?

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    // add a script that creates a new instance of an object from the caller's namespace
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI <URI>
Import-PSSession $session
$configuration = Get-MailboxAutoReplyConifguration -identity <E-Mail>

# Put it on the output stream
$configuration
    ");

    // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

    // loop through each output object item
    foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
    {
        if (outputItem != null)
        {
            if(outputItem.BaseObject.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Management.MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration"){
                # We have a decrepancy here as the above is the Exchange API class and 
                # below would be the EWS API class. As they expose the same attributes I'd expect it to work.
                OofSettings settings = outputItem.BaseObject as OofSettings
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly the problem: The Deserialization destroys the original Powershell-Object your script generated and create a new one, with the data of the origin object, but not the methods afaik (Type PSObject).

The workaround is to do the task you have to do in a powershell-script either or directly in the first script (whatever fits better to your needs).

For your example, i mean this:

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    // add a script that creates a new instance of an object from the caller's namespace
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI <URI>
Import-PSSession $session
$configuration = Get-MailboxAutoReplyConifguration -identity <E-Mail>
***INSERT HERE Powershell-Cmdlets to do the things you need***

# Put it on the output stream
$configuration
    ");

    // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

    // loop through each output object item
    foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
    {
        if (outputItem != null)
        {
            if(outputItem.BaseObject.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Management.MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration"){
                # We have a decrepancy here as the above is the Exchange API class and 
                # below would be the EWS API class. As they expose the same attributes I'd expect it to work.
                OofSettings settings = outputItem.BaseObject as OofSettings
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually need that object in the C# part as it's part of a ASP.NET MVC application and I need to display the information. My solution was/is to check for the type (just using `outputItem.ToString()` as it has the original type) and use `outputItem.Properties['key'].Value` to access the attributes.